# server script keeps sending emails when it shouldn't

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ip

I wrote a script to run from the cron every 5 minutes.

It takes the existing IP in a file called "nowipaddr" and then runs an if loop to check the new IP with the existing IP and if both the IP's remain same, it can skip sending an email. Else if there is a change in IP it should send an email with the new IP.

The problem is that it still sends me an email every 5 minutes, whether there is a change in IP or not. If there is a change, it updates the file "nowipaddr" with the new IP and sends the email. If there is no change, it does the same.

I copied the code from this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/374894/server-script-that-sends-an-email-every-time-the-global-ip-changes?fbclid=IwAR3mU7n5oMEMcJPTV8P5y8Icy01x4-iH4Bc6Lck3vWJNUHNxaCNJUtmvElg

```
#!/bin/bash
NOWIPADDR="/home/scripts/nowipaddr"
GETIPADDR="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
LOG="/home/scripts/ip.log"
timestamp=$( date +%T )
curDate=$( date +"%m-%d-%y" )

if [ -f $NOWIPADDR ]; then
    if [[ `$GETIPADDR` = $(< $NOWIPADDR) ]]; then
        echo $curDate $timestamp " IP address check: " $(< $NOWIPADDR) >> $LOG
    else
        $GETIPADDR > $NOWIPADDR
        mail -s "New Server IP" email@gmail.com < $NOWIPADDR
    fi
else
    curl $GETIPADDR > $NOWIPADDR
    mail -s "Server IP" email@gmail.com < $NOWIPADDR
fi
```

I want it to send an email just when there's a change in IP

Comment: Have you done anything to try to debug the issue?

Comment: What is the message in the email? `New Server IP` or just `Server IP`?

Comment: You should run `$GETIPADDR` once, and save the result in a variable. Otherwise, it could change between comparing it and writing to the file.

Comment: BTW, it's a bad idea to use all-uppercase variable names. That's conventionally reserved for environment variables, and you could run into conflicts (but probably not with these variables).

Comment: `curl $GETIPADDR` makes no sense. `$GETIPADDR` isn't valid arguments to `curl`.

Comment: These redirections.....

Comment: @Barmar the message is `New Server IP`

Comment: I copied your script and I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the code that seem to work well, though I would like to make sure it's the right way

```
#!/bin/bash
NOWIPADDR="/home/scripts/nowipaddr"
GETIPADDR="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
LOG="/home/scripts/ip.log"
timestamp=$( date +%T )
curDate=$( date +"%m-%d-%y" )

if [ -f $NOWIPADDR ]; then
   if [ `cat $NOWIPADDR` = `$GETIPADDR` ]; then
     echo $curDate $timestamp " IP address check: " `cat $NOWIPADDR` >> $LOG
   else
     $GETIPADDR > $NOWIPADDR
     mail -s "New Server IP" email@gmail.com < $NOWIPADDR
   fi
else
   curl $GETIPADDR > $NOWIPADDR
   mail -s "Server IP" email@gmail.com < $NOWIPADDR
fi
```

I changed

```
if [[ `$GETIPADDR` = $(< $NOWIPADDR) ]]; then
```

to

```
if [ `cat $NOWIPADDR` = `$GETIPADDR` ]; then
```

based on the other answer from the same link

Comment: You still have the unnecessary `curl` at the end. That was clearly a mistake in the post you copied from (he was modifying one of the other answers, which gets the IP from a website).

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why? Why are you inconsistent about your use of backticks and `$(...)`?

Comment: I changed `if [[ '$GETIPADDR' = $(< $NOWIPADDR) ]]; then` for `if [ 'cat $NOWIPADDR' = '$GETIPADDR' ]; then` based on the other answer from the same link

Comment: That information should be in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: You should explain *why* the change was necessary. I think `$(cat filename)` should be equivalent to `$(< filename)`, so explain why this makes a difference.

Comment: ok I'll add it, but even though it works I woulld like to make sure if it looks like the good answer

Comment: You have quotes instead of backticks in the explanation.

Comment: @Barmar I would like to know it as well, it was just trial and error